# iPhone Application logic

Tags: iphone, ios

I need to develop a client application for a site that host and show images.
The client should shows all new images and take a picture and send to website.

I'm a newbie to iOS programming so this question:

In an application alike this, there's the need to create a Model? I ask this question because I think I can do anything with Controllers but maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MVC pattern as used in Mac OS and iOS applications isn't something best explained in an answer box but here's a link to some [simple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH32-SW1) about the roles of Models, Views and Controllers

Some good basic introductions to start with, which also have relevant links to the next stage of documentation are:

- [Cocoa Core Competencies](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/AccessorMethod.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH2-SW1)
- [Cocoa Application Competencies for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/Animation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009071-CH11-SW1)

Read these excellent articles first. You'll learn better and faster if you do some basic reading.

Answer (score 3):

While there is never a "need" to create a model, it's good form to do so, and it'll likely save you many headaches down the road. Ultimately, you're going to need to deal with images and websites and how they interact with each other and whatnot, so you might as well do it in models from the outset.

I'm as guilty as anyone for wanting to see immediate results and hack together something quickly, but I always regret it later on, and have to spend more time than I'd expected refactoring it into something usable.

Comment: Thanks for you useful reply-experience. In an application like this, what's the exact role of a model? Probably I need to read something on iOS models because I never used them.

Comment: Models are not something specific to iOS. They're just classes that keep related information together. For instance, you might have an image and a description of the image. You could put them both into an NSDictionary, and then put the dictionary into an NSArray, or you could create a new MyThing object, which has both an image and description, and put that into an NSArray. The dictionary will work, sure, but it starts to get more awkward as you add more attributes. Put it into a model class and go.

Comment: Yes I want to create a class like "Post" that includes image and the description. For example in the first view you can see the popular images grid list. These images are in array "images". And so I put images array in the model. But the model is one right? I mean a model manage this array throughout the application. (NB images are updated every tot minutes) I'm a bit confused on "how to use" a model in my ios application. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You should read up on creating and using classes and properties in Objective C.